# TextWriterTraceListener does not work

Tags: c#, .net, logging, trace, system.diagnostics

Config file:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add name="Console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" initializeData="false"></add>
        <add name="Text" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\uat\logs\bifit.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime"></add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

The code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Running BiFit Test Server.");
             }
         }
```

I can see the text in cosole window. And the file is created, but it empty.
I remember there is something like Autoflush property somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You recall correctly - it is defined on the [`trace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe8whywc.aspx) element:

```
<trace autoflush="true">
  ...
</trace>
```

> autoflush - Optional attribute. Specifies whether the trace listeners automatically flush the output buffer after every write operation.

Comment: Thanks, but then this attribute applies to all listeners. But the console listeners works unlike file one.

Comment: @Captain Comic - Can't change how it works, I'm afraid. And does it matter if the console output buffer also gets flushed?

Comment: @Captain Comic - Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      ...
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could call Trace.Flush() once you are done with your Trace.Write type operations.