# Writing debug output to a .txt file in C#

Tags: c#

I'm running code and I want my debug output to write to a text file. How does this work?

I tried to write:

```
TextWriterTraceListener[] listeners = new TextWriterTraceListener[] {
            new TextWriterTraceListener("W:\\C.txt"),
            new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out)};
Debug.Listeners.AddRange(listeners);
Debug.WriteLine("Some Value", "Some Category");
```

But it still writes to the output window...

What should I do?

Comment: You want to a file and *not* to the console? Take out `new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out)`...?

Comment: You are right...what should choose instead of (Console.out) in order to write to text file?

Comment: The thing is, it looks like you have *both* in your example: console and text file. Like I said, *don't* specify `Console.Out`, because you will get both. Either remove that *one* line from your array, or just add only a `new TextWriterTraceListener(...)` to `Debug.Listeners`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Trace.WriteLine("text")`. It's designed exactly for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My text file still empty

Comment: You have an example in the link provided by Monika.

Answer (score 7):

I found answer on Stack Overflow look at:
*[Writing C# debug output to .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926577/writing-c-sharp-debug-output-to-txt-file)*

1. Add listener to Trace
2. Use trace.

In your case you didn't call [Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) for putting record to file.

```
TextWriterTraceListener[] listeners = new TextWriterTraceListener[] {
            new TextWriterTraceListener("W:\\C.txt"),
            new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out)};
Debug.Listeners.AddRange(listeners);
Debug.WriteLine("Some Value", "Some Category");
Debug.Flush()
```